# 'guice.injector-source' property has been deprecated. Add a class implementing 'io.cucumber.guice.InjectorSource' on the glue path instead

Tags: guice, cucumber-java

I have upgraded my build.gradle to the latest versions, but now i see this error - 'guice.injector-source' property has been deprecated. Add a class implementing 'io.cucumber.guice.InjectorSource' on the glue path instead

I had my Injector file path mentioned in cucumber.properties, looks like with the new version its a different way to do it now?

Because of this, it says that my implementations are not bound.

'cucumber-guice', version: '7.8.1'
'guice', version: '4.1.0'

I have been trying to figure out the way to put the class implementing 'io.cucmber.guice.InjectorSource on the glue path. Could not find any solution yet.

Note : I did not upgrade guice to '5.1.0' cause I am not able to resolve the issue - could not find - guice-no_app.jar (different issue planning to resolve later)

Answer (score 1):

The glue path is the package that contains your step definitions, hooks and other code needed by Cucumber. If configured in `cucumber.properties` you should see something like:

```
cucumber.glue=com.example.app
```

Then you can put your `InjectorSource` implementation in `src/test/java/com/example/app` and implement it like so:

```java
package com.example.app

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.Stage;
import io.cucumber.guice.CucumberModules;
import io.cucumber.guice.InjectorSource;
public class YourInjectorSource implements InjectorSource {
    @Override
    public Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(Stage.PRODUCTION, CucumberModules.createScenarioModule(), new YourModule());
    }
}
```

You can read more about the module in its docs:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-guice

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on M.P. Korstanje's answer:

Prior to cucumber-guice version 7.x you need a *cucumber.properties* file that tells cucumber how to find your main Guice module. In this case, it should contain something like:

**Cucumber properties**

```
guice.injector-source=com.acme.MainModule
```

After version 7.x, instead, you need to create an additional class inside your glue directory that implements the InjectorSource interface. *Cucumber.properties* is no longer used for referencing the MainModule class as far as I can tell, so it probably can be deleted.

Here is Junit class that runs Cucumber, configured with a glue directory:

```
package com.acme.cucumber;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
    // step definitions go inside the 'glue' directory
    glue = {"com/acme/steps")

public class CukeRunner {}
```

Here is the additional class that is required. Note that the package declared is the glue directory where the step definitions are stored.

```
package com.acme.steps;

public class InjectorSourceStepDef implements InjectorSource {
    @Override
    public Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new MainModule());
    }
}
```

You could make one of your existing Step Definitions implement the interface, but I think a separate class is cleaner. Be careful not to implement InjectorSource more than once.